# Smart Contracts for the Blind Auctions

Tags: solidity, transactions, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp, auctions

In blind auctions from solidity documentation what value should I insert under the bid function?Even I inserted string value,integer value under the bid function but it is showing the error as invalid value..[image]..

Comment: It is better to include the code as text that way it is easier to copy and test.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the function's parameters `bid(bytes32 _blindedBid)`, it's a `bytes32` type. An example of a valid `bytes32` value is `0x6b5fc80c91d15ca5b4cf5b965ce20114777022aec8a50912bacde96a9558b22e`. But yeah, you need to pass in a `bytes32` value that makes sense to you.

You can find some comments written above the `bid` function in the code, they are to guide you through this. Let's see what's there:

```
    /// Place a blinded bid with `_blindedBid` =
    /// keccak256(abi.encodePacked(value, fake, secret)).
    /// The sent ether is only refunded if the bid is correctly
    /// revealed in the revealing phase. The bid is valid if the
    /// ether sent together with the bid is at least "value" and
    /// "fake" is not true. Setting "fake" to true and sending
    /// not the exact amount are ways to hide the real bid but
    /// still make the required deposit. The same address can
    /// place multiple bids.
    function bid(bytes32 _blindedBid)
        public
        payable
        onlyBefore(biddingEnd)
    {
        bids[msg.sender].push(Bid({
            blindedBid: _blindedBid,
            deposit: msg.value
        }));
    }
```

I generally use `ethersjs` to do the hashing and abi encoding/decoding stuff. But here, since you are using remix, I'd suggest to add this function to your solidity code:

```
function generateBlindedBidBytes32(uint256 value, bool fake, bytes32 secret) public view returns (bytes32) {
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(value, fake, secret));
}
```

This helper function simply encodes your bid amount into a blinded bid `bytes32` value, which you can pass to the `bid` function. Use this function from remix just to prepare your blinded bid. The first argument `value` is the amount of wei. Second argument `fake`, set it as false if you want that bid to not be a fake bid. Third argument `secret`, pass any random bytes32 value from somewhere on the internet (my quick source of `bytes32` value is etherscan's latest transaction hashes).